# Display list of tensors as image

Tags: python, input, pytorch, dataset, imshow

I have problem to display list of tensors that contain list of  two images as one
combine

```
def load_pair(fname):
mat = loadmat(fname)
# A for image 1, B for image 2
A = im2tensor(mat['ImgStruct'][0][0][0][:, :, None]).to(device)
B = im2tensor(mat['ImgStruct'][0][0][1][:, :, None]).to(device)
return A, B
```

loading the image

```
img_pairs = []
for ind_str in ['003', '004', '006', '008', '009', '010', '011', '012', '014']:
   A, B = load_pair('Tubul/ImgPair_' + ind_str + '.mat')

img_pairs.append((A, B))
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Can you be more specific what is the desired output you are looking for?

Comment: yes, thank you for the help. I'm trying to display list of tensor that contain two Images for example : image 003 it contain 2 images  and I just want to display the image before it enter to the network. I tried to use "imshow" function but it didn't work because the type of the variable is tensor and not numpy

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.